# How do I sync my contacts between my Exchange and Hotmail accounts?

Tags: email, sync, exchange, hotmail

I keep all my contacts in my work email account (MS Exchange with Outlook 2010) and also use Hotmail for emails (e.g. myname@live.com). I would like to be able to access all my Exchange contacts when I send an email from Hotmail.

How do I sync my contacts between my Exchange and Hotmail accounts?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I've got the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

It's not syncing, but you could copy them over to your Hotmail Contact list within Outlook, when you have the [**Outlook Hotmail Connector**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/microsoft-office-outlook-hotmail-connector-overview-HA010222518.aspx) installed.

You have to hold down CTRL while dragging them across, otherwise they get moved instead.

Alternatively,  I think you may be able to do it with [**Plaxo Premium**](http://www.plaxo.com/), but I am not sure. I only use the standard service.

[**Synrc**](http://sync.codeplex.com/) is something that I just remembered as well.  I seem to remember having some sort of difficulty with it, but it was quite a long time ago, so I have forgotten what it was.

Comment: @Craig HB: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the product recommendations -- I'll check them out